# PowerApps collection not cleared after closing app

Tags: powerapps

I have a collection in my PowerApp called `Collection1`.
I also have a gallery called `Gallery1`. I use the collection to keep track if all checkboxes are checked in the gallery, so then I can enable a button.

`AgreeCheckbox` in `Gallery1` has the following actions:

- `OnCheck: Collect(Collection1,ThisItem)`
- `OnUncheck: Remove(Collection1,ThisItem)`

And then the button has the following displaymode:

```
If(CountRows(Collection1) = CountRows(Gallery1.AllItems), 
DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)
```

I'm currently running the App in preview mode, but sometimes items get stuck in `Collection1` and next time the button is enabled even if only half of the checkboxes are checked (I have 6 currently, and intermittently 2 or 3 items get stuck in the `Collection1`.

I've added `OnStart: Clear(Collection1)` to `Screen1` (where all this is happening), but this didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar mechanic in my apps, so I can help you with this. Can you let me know what you have set the Default property of AgreeCheckbox to?

Answer (score 0):

- I have had similar issue. The issue is basically due to PowerApps uses Cache.
- Not only in prieveiw mode but also when you publish the app sometimes it is higly cached.
- I guess  Clear(Collection1) shall be a good Idea you used and will help, but as said before it lies on Cache of Browser, try using CTRL+F5 and do refresh so that it will be refreshed from Server side and shall reload the app even in preview mode.

I hope this helps.